# Return airdropped lamports on devnet and testnet?

Tags: devnet, testnet, airdrop

I feel guilty taking airdrops and putting them into accounts that I never use again. Is there a way to return the airdropped lamports? Or should I not be so caring? I don't want to hog all the lamports to myself...

I can't be trusted to keep devnet and testnet private keys either.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return your used lamports you can send them back to the faucet. This is `9B5XszUGdMaxCZ7uSQhPzdks5ZQSmWxrmzCSvtJ6Ns6g` on devnet.